# Designing a different grammer that generates same expression

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I've a set of grammar rules like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
&S \to AbB \\
&A \to aA|\epsilon \\
&B \to aB|bB|\epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

The grammar generates the following words:
$$
\begin{gather*}
AbB \to a^2AB \to a^3AB \to \cdots \to a^nAB \to a^nB \to \\
\to a^nB \to a^nbB \to a^nb^2B \to \cdots \to a^nb^mB \to a^nb^m,
\end{gather*}
$$
so if I did things right, $L(G) = a^n b^m$.
I think that $G$ is a type 1 grammar.

Now I need to design a more restrictive type of grammar that generates the same expression, and I'm stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

My attempt according to the collapsar's answer:

$$
\begin{align*}
&S \to aSA|b \\
&A \to a|b \\
&
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: @SpiderRico You referred to $L(G)$ as a type 1 [grammar], but $L(G)$ is a language. I changed this to $G$ being type 1. Your grammar is in fact context-free (type 2), and you want to change it to regular (type 3).

Comment: Your $L(G)$ is not correct: observe that $B$ expands to arbitrary sequences over $\{a,b\}$ while $A$ only produces sequences of $a$. Thus $L(G) = a^* b (a|b)^*$.